# EventMachine/em-http-request Detect when http stream connection is stalled

Tags: ruby, twitter, eventmachine, http-streaming

I'm using EventMachine + em-http-request to request Twitter streaming API.
It works perfectly, but now I would like to get it error proof.

What would be the best way to detect that the connection is stalled? (in order to try an auto-reconnect).

I have a temporary solution: each time I receive a new chunk from the stream method, I save the current timestamp. A PeriodicTimer is checking this timestamp and issues a reconnection whenever the last-timestamp is more than 30secs old. The issue with this solution is that it makes no difference between a stalled connection and a working connection with no content.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since your are using http which uses TCP connections you should be notified when a disconnect occurs. I am not sure how em-hhtp-request handles it but I am sure it does, just do some tests with a local server.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach an `errback` callback to your request object:

```
http.errback { puts 'error or timeout' }
```

From the em-http-request [wiki](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/wiki/Issuing-Requests):

> Errback function is invoked only in the case of a failed connection such as a timeout or bad DNS hostname.

Personally, I prefer to use Faraday rather than working with the raw em-http-request library:

```
require 'faraday'

http = Faraday.new do |b|
  b.adapter :em_http
end

res = http.get 'http://whatcodecraves.com'
puts res.body
```

Here's a [tutorial for Faraday](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/3/12/faraday-one-http-client-to-rule-them-all). And if you're working with the twitter streaming API, [here's a gotcha](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/processing#Gzip_and_EventMachine) to watch out for. Good luck!